# How to insert XML into another XML file ( REST API )

Tags: ruby, xml, rest

I need to pass to an application which uses REST API parameters in following XML file

```
paramValue = "<tag><stillonetag>value</stillonetag></tag>"
xmlIn = '
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251"?>
 <vco:execution-context xmlns:vco="http://www.vmware.com/vco" xmlns="vco">
     <vco:parameters>
         <vco:parameter name="inputXml" type="string" description="" scope="local">     
             <vco:string>#{paramValue}</vco:string>
         </vco:parameter>
      </vco:parameters>
 </vco:execution-context>
'
xmlExec = xmlIn.gsub(/\>[\s\n\r]+\</, '><')
response = HTTParty.post("/workflows/#{id}/presentation/instances/", { :basic_auth => @auth, :body => xmlExec})
```

With "normal" strings I do not have any issues, however in this case parameter inputXML expects value as a XML string. How can I embed such XML string into the ruby constant above?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you can try backslash \

Comment: Well, @Vikram I already tried to escape > and < with backslashes_but without success :(

Comment: Embed it as cdata? Or as an actual node?

Comment: What is `xmlIn2` used for? What is `xmlIn`? You have undefined and unexplained variables and want us to help you?

Answer (score 0):

Rule one: Do NOT try to process HTML or XML using regular expressions. They'll make you lose sleep.

Instead use the right tool, an XML parser. [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) is my tool of choice:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml_in2 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251"?>
 <vco:execution-context xmlns:vco="http://www.vmware.com/vco" xmlns="vco">
     <vco:parameters>
         <vco:parameter name="inputXml" type="string" description="" scope="local">     
             <vco:string>put parameter value here</vco:string>
         </vco:parameter>
      </vco:parameters>
 </vco:execution-context>
'

doc = Nokogiri.XML(xml_in2)

doc.at('//vco:string').content = 'new and improved text'

puts doc.to_xml
```

Which outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251"?>
<vco:execution-context xmlns:vco="http://www.vmware.com/vco" xmlns="vco">
     <vco:parameters>
         <vco:parameter name="inputXml" type="string" description="" scope="local">
             <vco:string>new and improved text</vco:string>
         </vco:parameter>
      </vco:parameters>
 </vco:execution-context>
```

Or, to insert XML:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml_in2 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251"?>
 <vco:execution-context xmlns:vco="http://www.vmware.com/vco" xmlns="vco">
     <vco:parameters>
         <vco:parameter name="inputXml" type="string" description="" scope="local">     
             <vco:string>put parameter value here</vco:string>
         </vco:parameter>
      </vco:parameters>
 </vco:execution-context>
'

doc = Nokogiri.XML(xml_in2)

doc.at('//vco:string').children = '<foo>some<bar>wild and crazy</bar>guys</foo>'

puts doc.to_xml
```

Resulting in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251"?>
<vco:execution-context xmlns:vco="http://www.vmware.com/vco" xmlns="vco">
     <vco:parameters>
         <vco:parameter name="inputXml" type="string" description="" scope="local">
             <vco:string><foo>some<bar>wild and crazy</bar>guys</foo></vco:string>
         </vco:parameter>
      </vco:parameters>
 </vco:execution-context>
```

---

EDIT:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml_in2 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251"?>
 <vco:execution-context xmlns:vco="http://www.vmware.com/vco" xmlns="vco">
     <vco:parameters>
         <vco:parameter name="inputXml" type="string" description="" scope="local">     
             <vco:string>put parameter value here</vco:string>
         </vco:parameter>
      </vco:parameters>
 </vco:execution-context>
'

doc = Nokogiri.XML(xml_in2)

doc.at('//vco:string').content = "<tag><stillonetag>value</stillonetag></tag>"

puts doc.to_xml
```

Which is now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251"?>
<vco:execution-context xmlns:vco="http://www.vmware.com/vco" xmlns="vco">
     <vco:parameters>
         <vco:parameter name="inputXml" type="string" description="" scope="local">
             <vco:string>&lt;tag&gt;&lt;stillonetag&gt;value&lt;/stillonetag&gt;&lt;/tag&gt;</vco:string>
         </vco:parameter>
      </vco:parameters>
 </vco:execution-context>
```

---

```
# encoding: UTF-8

require 'nokogiri'

xml_in2 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251"?>
 <vco:execution-context xmlns:vco="http://www.vmware.com/vco" xmlns="vco">
     <vco:parameters>
         <vco:parameter name="inputXml" type="string" description="" scope="local">     
             <vco:string>put parameter value here</vco:string>
         </vco:parameter>
      </vco:parameters>
 </vco:execution-context>
'

doc = Nokogiri.XML(xml_in2)
doc.encoding = 'UTF-8'

doc.at('//vco:string').content = "<operation>информация</operation>"

puts doc.to_xml
```

And the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vco:execution-context xmlns:vco="http://www.vmware.com/vco" xmlns="vco">
     <vco:parameters>
         <vco:parameter name="inputXml" type="string" description="" scope="local">
             <vco:string>&lt;operation&gt;информация&lt;/operation&gt;</vco:string>
         </vco:parameter>
      </vco:parameters>
 </vco:execution-context>
```

The "magic line" `# encoding: UTF-8` tells Ruby that the character encoding in the script is UTF-8. There are other encodings available. Prior to Ruby v2.0, it assumed the content was ASCII. v2.0+ assumes UTF-8.

At runtime, Nokogiri will assume that too, until it tries to parse a document. If the XML declaration specifies a character set, Nokogiri assumes that information is correct and that all characters in the XML will match that. XML is a strict specification, so the encoding must match the actual character bytes entered.

In the above sample I told Ruby, and Nokogiri, that I was using UTF-8. The XML document's declaration says it's `Win-1251`. Because I use a UTF-8 based system and was pasting in UTF-8 content, I told Nokogiri to change its understanding of the document's encoding by using `doc.encoding = "UTF-8"` to get everything in sync. After that, because Ruby, the pasted string, and Nokogiri are in agreement, the resulting XML will be correctly encoded.

The reason this is important is because some characters have to be encoded correctly in order for the XML to be valid. Embedded tags, and often Unicode characters, can't be stuck into the document in raw form, per the spec, so Nokogiri transforms them into the right encoding.

Trying to do this by hand for a very simple document is easy. As the document's complexity increases, or the inserted text gets longer, the problem rapidly grows.

Comment: Hi, @theTinMan, thanks a lot, but the issue is not that I cannot insert text into the variable properly. The issue is that the XML text is not recognized

Comment: You really haven't give us enough to work with. WHAT is `XMLin` you want to insert into? What is `XMLin2` used for in your code? What do you mean it's not "recognized"? By HTTPClient? By the far side you're sending it to? Is the XML you're generating invalid? We can only help you to the extent you explain what is going on.

Comment: Hi, @theTinMan the goal is very simple - I need to pass inside tjhe XML object ( xmlIn ) between the <vco:string> </vco:string> a string, which contains XML object (paramValue ) but should not be interpreted as XML text by the REST engine. The REST engine should parse the xmlIn text, and pass the parameter <vco:parameter> and its value <vco:string> to application program. And the application program sjhould in turn parse the rest of XML.When I use Nokogiri I get an XML object and my embedded part is interpretted as the part of external XML object

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!!!!
to pass the XML text as value for XML tag inside of another XML object without making it a part of this object

```
   I need to use &lt; and &gt; instead of < and >.
```

In my example it should be

```
   paramValue = "&lt;tag>&lt;stillonetag&gt;value&lt;/stillonetag&gt;&lt;/tag&gt;"
```

So long, XML experts!

Comment: If you need to embed XML as encoded text, then it's easy to do with a parser, so it's still done correctly. See the edit on my answer. Knowledge of which character to encode is built-into Nokogiri, as is the ability to use CDATA sections if HTML-encoding the tags isn't sufficient or desired.

Comment: @theTinMan Well, from my point of view, better to have an simple solution, that works, than a genial and complicated (nokogiri), that does not work. I need to use cyrillic letters in XML, but when I try  docExCon.at( '//vco:string' ).content = '<operation>информация</operation>'  I get encoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xE8 0xED 0xF4 0xEE
I/O error : encoder error so I need to rewrite my code completely from scratch using something less brilliant that nokogiri, but working ;-)

Comment: No, the problem is not Nokogiri, it's your understanding of how Ruby handles multibyte characters. Nokogiri is fully UTF-8 and Unicode compliant to handle XML correctly, but it expects you to do things correctly. You don't want to so Ruby complains. You keep adding new conditions and requirements to your question instead of presenting them from the start. I think you decided you know the answer and don't want to learn the correct way to deal with it. Good luck. It'll be a bumpy ride.